# How to set the value received from the response to .js or json file

Tags: javascript, api, cucumber, karate

I am using the karate api framework to automate web services.
Currently, I am facing problem to set the response value back to the .js or JSON file which I receive from the cucumber feature file.

```
My response:{"authorizationtoken" : "58102a8c9e074d578edae8f3d5e96001'}
```

How can I save this to .js or JSON file to reuse them in other scripts [feature files] ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot save the value to a `.js` or `JSON` file provided you don't want to write the value to a json file

You can assign the value to a variable , let say using  a namespacing technique to avoid collision

```
var nameSpaceObject = {
    authKey : "",
    someOtherFunctionIfNecessary :function(){}

};
```

Then you can call this name space & assign value to it

```
var response =  {"authorizationtoken" : "58102a8c9e074d578edae8f3d5e96001' }
  nameSpaceObject.authKey = response.authorizationtoken;
```

Comment: agree with @brk - you should never need to save anything to files in an API test.. it sounds like what the poster is trying to do is set auth headers in a re-usable way. please read the karate doc on configure headers.